# Eliminate duplicate rows inside GROUP_CONCAT

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, group-concat

I have duplicate records using this sql:

```
SELECT emp.id, first_name, second_name, last_name, department, positions,  
            GROUP_CONCAT(email, " ", email_type SEPARATOR " || ") AS mails,
            GROUP_CONCAT(number, " ", number_type SEPARATOR " || ") AS numbers
            FROM geography.employee AS emp
            INNER JOIN geography.employee_email AS ee ON emp.id = ee.email_FK
            LEFT JOIN geography.employee_number AS en ON emp.id = en.number_FK
            WHERE first_name = 'John' AND last_name = 'Ausini'
            GROUP BY emp.id
```

So I get these results for mails:

```
heyhey@abv.bg personal || heyhey@abv.bg personal || summer_geals@bwtc.co work || summer_geals@bwtc.co work || ivanov@abv.bg personal || ivanov@abv.bg personal
```

and for numbers:

```
+7654656656565 work || +7654656465655 personal || +7654656656565 work || +7654656465655 personal || +7654656656565 work || +7654656465655 personal
```

The strange thing is that in my second record the mails are not duplicating, mails:

```
hei@abv.bg personal || hurei@abv.bg personal || burei@abv.bg personal || work@bwtc.com work
```

...but in this record I do not have numbers and maybe this deffers it from the top one.
My expected output is not repeating data per record as such(for first record example):

```
heyhey@abv.bg personal || summer_geals@bwtc.co work || ivanov@abv.bg personal
```

...and no duplicates for the numbers too.
DISTINCT is not working too(if I put it after the SELECT), I tried it although I am not fan of masking up the problem.

My data in the tables:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: When you join multiple one-to-many relations, the number results will be multiplied by the separate multi-matches. If you were to look at the results of similar a non-grouping query, you would see each phone number paired with each email.

Comment: This group by helps me for the group_concat, because I need to get the data for two records with the same names. If I remove the group by I get the mails of two records of John Ausini in one column. @RaymondNijland

Comment: Also keep in mind GROUP_CONCAT cuts the string i believe the defualt is around 1000 bytes you need to set the value higher manually it's in the MySQL manual..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're only getting the information for a single user, I would go with Salman A's answer; but if you were going for multiple (or all) users, and users tend to have lots of emails and numbers, this version *could be* faster.

```
SELECT emp.id, first_name, second_name, last_name, department, positions, ee.mails, en.numbers
FROM geography.employee AS emp
INNER JOIN (SELECT email_FK, GROUP_CONCAT(email, " ", email_type SEPARATOR " || ") AS mails 
            FROM geography.employee_email 
            GROUP BY email_FK
) AS ee ON emp.id = ee.email_FK
LEFT JOIN (SELECT number_FK, GROUP_CONCAT(number, " ", number_type SEPARATOR " || ") AS numbers 
           FROM geography.employee_number 
           GROUP BY number_FK
) AS en ON emp.id = en.number_FK
;
```

Comment: @Ivanp Also keep in mind GROUP_CONCAT cuts the string i believe the defualt is around 1000 bytes you need to set the value higher manually it's in the MySQL manual.. Use `SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = @@max_allowed_packet;` before you run this query

Comment: Definitely worth mentioning, especially since it can be configured lower; but I think for this particular scenario 1000 would be more than enough for all but the most prolific of email account holders. _Though I did say "lots of emails and numbers."_

Answer (score 3):

MySQL [`GROUP_CONCAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) allows you to specify `DISTINCT` which should eliminate duplicates before concatenation:

```
SELECT
    emp.id, first_name, second_name, last_name, department, positions,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT email, " ", email_type SEPARATOR " || ") AS mails,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT number, " ", number_type SEPARATOR " || ") AS numbers
FROM geography.employee AS emp
INNER JOIN geography.employee_email AS ee ON emp.id = ee.email_FK
LEFT JOIN geography.employee_number AS en ON emp.id = en.number_FK
WHERE first_name = 'John' AND last_name = 'Ausini'
GROUP BY emp.id
```

Comment: `SELECT emp.id, first_name, second_name, last_name, department, positions ... GROUP BY emp.id` looks suspect.. As it is not a valid way to use SQL's `GROUP BY`..

Comment: It's valid for MySQL under certain configurations.

Comment: Yes it run if the MySQL server does not run sql_mode ONLY FULL GROUP BY.. But the values for first_name, second_name, last_name, department, positions column will not match the group emp.id

Comment: It's [ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by); newer MySQL versions' default configurations require it. And in this particular instance, it is trivial to fix it for such configurations with just `GROUP BY emp.id, first_name, second_name, last_name, department, positions`. _Pretty much any query that was not an abuse of this feature can be converted easily,_

Comment: " it is called "partial group by" and allowed in MySQL" i know actually it's called "functional dependency" it only works when emp.id is a PRIMARY or UNIQUE key and all selected column are selected from the emp alias

Comment: @RaymondNijland it this particular example it will work just fine. `emp.id` is the primary key.

Comment: true emp.id looks to be a PRIMARY KEY and a selected column comes from the same table now i look better to the data image.. Then MySQL can indeed use "functional dependency".. I advice you not the get used by this  "functional dependency" feature most databases don't support this feature. Only database i believe which also support this is SQL Server